# Segue between 2 separate Collection Views on 1 view controller

Tags: uicollectionview, uistoryboardsegue

I have a view controller with two collectionviews being displayed. I now want to segue from both collection views to different destination controllers. I have this code below but no luck.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{

JSTRCollectionViewCell *selectedCell = (JSTRCollectionViewCell *)sender;
JSTRBrowserViewController *targetVC = (JSTRBrowserViewController *) [segue destinationViewController];
targetVC.ndesc = selectedCell.description.text;
targetVC.ntitle = selectedCell.title.text;
targetVC.nimage = selectedCell.image.image;
targetVC.ncat = selectedCell.category.text;
targetVC.ndate = selectedCell.date.text;

SliderCollectionViewCell *selectedCell1 = (SliderCollectionViewCell *)sender;
SliderBrowserViewController *targetVC1 = (SliderBrowserViewController *) [segue destinationViewController];
targetVC1.sldesc = selectedCell1.description.text;
targetVC1.sldate = selectedCell1.date.text;
targetVC1.slcat = selectedCell1.category.text;
targetVC1.sltitle = selectedCell1.title.text;
targetVC1.slimage = selectedCell1.image.image;
}
```

Comment: Give the two segues different identifiers. You can then check these using an if-statement. Or you could use `isMemberOfClass` on the destinationViewController of the segue to check which segue is being performed.

Comment: [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"String" sender:indexPath];
the segue identifiers worked like a charm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this to the collectionview cells

```
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"String" sender:indexPath];
```

and added an if statement to the segue and problem solved.